# String Hashing C++

Tags: c++, string, math, hash, hashtable

I am trying to compute the hash for a given string. The working algorithm is given below. Size refers to the size of the hashtable to make sure I do not index outside of the array. Originally, I coded line 4 as `hash+=aPrime*hash + s.at(i)` as per an algorithm I found on multiple sources. However, I got Bus error: 10 from that. When I changed that line to as it is shown below it seemed to work but I do not why. It would be great if someone could help me understand why the second line works but the first one does not.

```
        int aPrime = 31;
        int hash = 0;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            hash += aPrime*hash * s.at(i);
        }
        return hash % size;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the `s.at()` call that's probably failing, which is usually an indication of going out of bounds. Are you sure all you changed was `+` to `*`? Is it possible your `hash` value exceeded ~2.1e9 and wrapped negative, which would be an invalid offset?

Comment: You need to do the modulo inside the loop or else it will overflow very quickly.

Comment: `hash % size` can be negative on some systems if `hash` is negative.  You'll want to check that to make sure it isn't negative.  (The usual way, `(hash + size) % size`, can still roll over and create a negative.)

Comment: It seems as though just doing abs(hash%size) works perfectly and the negative seemed to be the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Rather than using abs, you can have `unsigned hash;` to make `hash` an unsigned value (i.e. it can never be negative in the first place).

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much!